# Get src attribute(video link) from an iframe on a separate(not owned by me) domain into my own website(dynamically)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, embed

Was wondering if it would be possible to aquire the **src attribute** from an **iframe**. This website though appears to have **dynamically** created said **iframe** through **javascript** with the video link in question. Is it  still possible?

Through using the jQuery function **$.get** to aquire the HTML of the website, I soon learnt that the **iframe was not placed right in the HTML**. With my current knowledge I could not find a solution to get to the src attribute of a **non-HTML created iframe**.

The **ultimate goal** of me making this **question** is to **dynamically** be able to **search** for a video which is **embeded** on a website(**have been completed**), and then copy said **embed(video)** to my **own**(**not affiliated**) website to be used **temporarily**. The embeds in question on said website are not meant to be used in this sort of way and does therefore not have userfriendly-method to accomplishing this(**tried searching for it but to no avail**).

Thank you to anyone who might be able to help me, and I also **do not care** about whether I'd have to include a separete library/api to complete this request, as results are the onlything that **matters** as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure @CluelessMinion,

you can programmatically get the src of an iframe with the following JS:

```js
document.getElementById('IFRAMEID').src;
```

where IFRAMEID is (obviously) the ID of the iframe (can be substituted for ClassName, TagName, etc, if ID is not given). See document.getElementsByClassName (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
See document.getElementsByTagName (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

If this doesn't work for you, feel free to tell me the specific error message, and I'll do my best to find something that DOES work.

Comment: The 'document' references the current webpage and therefore is not applicable to the task at hand. I am trying to call a script(javascript) on my website to then grab an element from a seperate website(different domain), specifically an iframe(with a video), to then get its src attribute. I am actually not trying to bring the whole embed with it but only the src so I can manually add it to an embed on my website. Sorry if this sounds confusing. But thanks for trying to help even though it did not quite work for me :)

Comment: In layman's terms, are you trying to get the source of an iframe located on a different website? Could you give a link to the website where the iframe is, if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. Though the website in question can seem odd to most. Guess this is the best time to reveal the whole scope of my project. Have you heard of the whole 'anime' and 'manga' scene and how there is not one website where both of them are accessible? The scope of my project is to make a website which has all the 'anime' and 'manga' at one place(Yes this is indeed cringe). Now returning to this matter. Have you heard of 9anime.to? If you don't please put on your best adblocker as the ads can seem questionable: https://9anime.to/watch/your-name.nkll/ep-full

Comment: Ok, this is the first thing that appeared. It is not exactly an iframe, but rather an anchor: <a id="lk88h" href="http://fifteenthprohibition.com/hsng8s6nc?sdz=49&amp;refer=https%3A%2F%2F9anime.to%2Fsearch%3Fkeyword%3Dtest&amp;kw=%5B%22results%22%2C%22for%22%2C%22test%22%2C%22anime%22%5D&amp;key=e451654ce39dadbfc0153e75d2c312ff&amp;scrWidth=1366&amp;scrHeight=768&amp;tz=-4&amp;v=21.1.v.1&amp;res=7.31&amp;dev=r&amp;uuid=99f92fa2-dbb3-4630-943b-a682631419a3%3A3%3A1" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: inherit;"></a>                           Is this what you wanted the src from a call

Comment: Update: I have been fiddling with the website given. It is a nightmare to deal with, as they block all iframe connections (typical), AS WELL AS any .get() requests. I successfully bypassed the CORS .get() restrictions with https://allorigins.win/, but they have employed another mechanism which uses a setTimeout before actually loading the page content, thereby giving any .get() a result of Redirecting.

Comment: Is there still a way? Or is it out of the question?

Comment: I can't even find anything identifying on the website. It looks like everything related to the videos is natively hosted and uploaded. Not even private Vimeos or YouTube are that careful... They're really opposed to someone ripping their videos... I'd find a different website if I were you, it'll save you time and effort in the long run that way, I think

Comment: Most of the websites hosting these kinds of videos use a similar method. Therefore finding a different one would be difficult... Are you sure there is not a way which one would be able to take in order to succeed? I humbly plead to you if there is one.

Comment: If you are able to rip any one of their videos, that is enough for me, as then I could try to continue on my own to figure out the rest. Though, thank you so much for even being able to come this far, couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: This might sound a little whiney. Though, could you be so kind as to share the code that was using allorigins.win? That is the code you mentioned on your third comment.

Comment: Sure:                                     $.getJSON('https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://9anime.to/home'), function (data) {
                      document.write(data.contents);
                  });                                 make sure to include your <script> tags and jquery!

Comment: You have been a great help to reach my dream project. If there are any more things I should keep in mind whilst trying to figure this out, please do tell them as I am up for any sort of solutions. Thanks for everything!

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help, @CluelessMinion! If you're not doing so already, I would recommend using GitHub to store your code and to track revisions, as well as get the added benefit of being able to host it online (for free). If you would like to do so, I can set-up a shared repo so we can solve this problem together. (I'm not really into Anime, but those websites have annoyed me, and I hate not knowing how to do something!)

Comment: Sorry for not being able to answer yesterday, as I did not have notifications turned on. If you are up for it, I would appreciate your help. Though I might not be able to match you in programming knowledge as I have not programmed much in javascript or used GitHub practically before. I hope there will not be any difficulties communicating. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yeah, it's no problem @CluelessMinion. We all have to learn at some point. I will create a new repo on my github at github.com/flancast90. To make it collaborative with you, I will need your username (preferably the GitHub url to it, so I can choose the correct user on the share option)

Comment: Sure, I have just created a GitHub now. Here is the url: https://github.com/CluelessMinion

Comment: just sent an invite to the "Animanga" repo. We can chat in the discussion tab there!